# Use of Russian (Cyrillic) in section title in English document

Tags: xetex, cyrillic

My document is chiefly in English, but from time to time I include other languages and scripts (Cyrillic, Greek, Arabic...) with no problem at all, e.g.:

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}Павлов, И. П.\end{otherlanguage}
```

I am using `XeLaTeX`. When I tried to include a whole chapter/section in Russian (Cyrillic), it didn't work. I tried to replicate the `\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}` thing in the chapter's section title without success.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! It's fine to ask a new question, in fact we prefer to keep issues separate. Can you please post a short, full example of what you are trying to do? See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: For large text blocks, the best option is usually `\selectlanguage`. See sections 1.2 and 1.7 in the `babel` manual: https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf .

Comment: Sure thing (and thanks for the editing, i'm still learning the ropes).  What I tried, very rudimentary, was simply this: <code>\chapter{\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}\textit{Всё новое — это хорошо забытое старое}\end{otherlanguage}}</code>

Comment: For short texts (a few words or sentences), don’t use `\selectlanguage` but `\foreignlanguage`.

Comment: thanks @javier-bezos.  does `\foreignlanguage` works with `XeLaTeX`? and does it work in a chapter title?

Comment: Sure, with `pdflatex`, `lualatex` and `xelatex` (and even in `plain` with the supported languages): `\chapter{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Всё новое}}`. Just try .

Comment: thanks a lot, @JavierBezos, it worked! now i have a minor issue with the absent `bold case` in the cyrl script, but i suppose that has to do with the fonts. i tried using `\textbf{}` but it didn't work. anyway, i got what i wanted thanks to you :)